# Need and JOption input for my calculation instead of system.output

Tags: java, input

What I want to happen is the for the "FOR" to have an  joption input for that calculation instead of the systems input

```
  String me = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a username!");
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your name is: " + me);
  String user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your choice!");
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your choice is: " + user);
  String numbers = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a set of numbers!");

  int n, c, fact = 1;

  if(user.equals("1"))
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "" + me + "" + numbers);

  else if(user.equals("2"))                
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number to calculate a Factoral Username");
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  n = in.nextInt();

  if ( n < 0 )
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ("Number should be non-negative."));

  else
  {
  for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
  fact = fact*c;

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ("New username is: " + me + fact));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the result of dialog call to variable and then convert it to integer:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number");
try {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(input);
    // ....
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Exception when input is not in integer format
    // or is null when user press cancel button
}
```

Comment: Where will I Put this?

Comment: Replace `Scanner` initialization and `nextInt` call with this code. Next put your code that should be run if given value is successfully parsed inside `try `block.